# Loading aspx page using jquery .load method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, squishit

In my page I have a dropdown that filter through the dining options that we have. I use jquery .load to reload the list. My problem is I'm using squishit to compress and combined my css/js files and I need to reference this again in the aspx page that I try to load. Am I doing it right? or is there a proper way of referencing the same css/javascript to the aspx page i'm loading?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO do not use .load function of jquery , since it will not work on IE 6,7 , instead i would use regular $.ajax().

Also you can use $.getScript() to load script to memory.